# Are there sequence points in member initial list?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a constructor as below:

```
Foo::Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar)
    : left(bar->getLeft()),
      right(bar->getRight()),
      mBar(std::move(bar)) {}
```

And the program crashed due to `bar` in `left(bar->getLeft())` is `nullptr`. If I use `left(mBar->getLeft())`, it works fine.

So I wondered if there's any sequence point in member initial list? If not, how to know for sure if the `move` statement happened or not? In another word: in this case, when to use argument and when to use member?

Comment: Can you show the order of data members in your class definition?

Comment: [This constructor and initializer list reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) could be helpful, especially the section about [initialization order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order).

Comment: This question is duplicated, thanks all.